# Comparison method violates its general contract even after checking for null

Tags: java, android

I am getting the below error

Unable to resume activity {com.xxx.yyy.zzz.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!

I am handling null cases for the string even then this error is coming. Any hints on what may be wrong. Code below

```
public class ConversationComparer implements Comparator<Conversation> {
@Override
public int compare(Conversation x, Conversation y) {

    if (x.getLastMessageDate() == null) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (y.getLastMessageDate() == null) {
        return -1;
    }

    return y.getLastMessageDate().compareTo(x.getLastMessageDate());

}}


public java.util.Date getLastMessageDate() {
        return lastMessageDate;
    }
```

This is how i use the comparator

```
if (conversationListAdapter != null) {
            Collections.sort(this.list,new ConversationComparer());
            conversationListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see that's wrong with it is you don't correctly handle the case where `x.getLastMessageDate()` and `y.getLastMessageDate()` are both `null`.

I think if you add this line to the beginning of the method it meets the contract.

```
if (x.getLastMessageDate() == null && y.getLastMessageDate() == null)
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should also check x and y again null and return 0 if both are null.

```
@Override
public int compare(Conversation x, Conversation y) {

   if (x == y || (x != null && y != null && x.getLastMessageDate() == y.getLastMessageDate()))
       return 0;    

   if (x == null)
       return 1;

   if (y == null)
       return -1;

   if (x.getLastMessageDate() == null)
       return 1;

   if (y.getLastMessageDate() == null)
       return -1;

   return y.getLastMessageDate().compareTo(x.getLastMessageDate());
}
```

Also, it would be interesting to know what data type "getLastMessageDate()" returns.

Comment: getlastmessage is java.util.Date

Comment: This is not antisymmetric. Suppose `x == null` and `y.getLastMessageDate() == null`. Then `compare(x, y) == 1` and `compare(y, x) == 1` too.

Comment: In that case I don't think your exception is coming from the compareTo method. Date.compareTo does not throw an InvalidArgumentException.  Maybe you provide the whole stack trace.

Comment: Yes I think it works now. +1 for bothering to deal with `x == null` and `y == null`.